# What does「お金どころじゃなく出てきた」mean?

Tags: meaning

I don't get the meaning of お金どころじゃなく出てきた below:

> お義父さんは別れる半年前に事業に失敗して借金を抱えてた。イライラして暴力を振るうようになって最後はもう**お金どころじゃなく出てきた**んだ。

I interpreted it as "[we] no longer have financial security..." I am uncertain about 出てきた.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the limited context provided in the first part of the excerpt,  this 出る probably just means "to leave" or "to get out", and the subject has implicitly switched to the speaker. Does the following fit the context?

> イライラして暴力を振るうようになって最後はもうお金どころじゃなく出てきたんだ。
>
> He became irritable and started to resort to violence. Eventually, it wasn't about the money anymore, so I left (home to come here).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not providing enough context. The speaker is a girl who transferred to a different school. When enquired why she didn't stay at her previous school, she explained that her parents got divorced, and her dad had money issues and she couldn't stay there longer. I now figured that 出てきた refers to leaving school.

Comment: @JohnDavies In that case, 出てきた may vaguely refer to "the place where I was" including both home and school.